# what is $ M^{\perp}$ given set?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $ ‎X=C[-1,1]‎$‎‎ be inner product space with definition $$‎\langle f,g‎‎‎\rangle =‎\int_{-1}^1 f‎‎ \overline{g}‎ ‎dt ‎‎.$$
Let $M$ be the subspace defined by
‎$$ ‎M= ‎‎\left\{f‎  \in ‎X\mid ‎f(t)=0 ,‎  ‎‎-1 \leq‎ t ‎‎\leq ‎0 \right\}. ‎$$

What is $M^{\perp}$?

Comment: the set of g orthogonal to M, that is, $\{g\in X:\forall f\in M, \langle g,f\rangle=0\}$.

Comment: bardy: I have another question, Is true equality $ M \bigoplus M^{\perp}=X$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not completely fluent in these matters. I would have to review, but roughly, that is somewhat true. But there may be counterexamples. If so, I'm sure there are conditions when it is guaranteed. For instance, we would have to say what type of space $M$ is possibly.

Comment: Try this: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Direct_Sum_of_Subspace_and_Orthocomplement.

Comment: Also, the definition of $M^\perp$ may depend on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N := \{\, g \in X \mid \text{$g(t) = 0$ for all $t \in (0, 1)$} \,\}$. I'll show that $M^\perp = N$.

From the definition of inner product, $N \subset M^\perp$ is obvious. So assume $g \in M^\perp$ and prove $g \in N$ by contradiction.

Suppose $g(\tau) \neq 0$ for some $\tau \in (0, 1)$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $g(\tau) > 0$. Since $g$ is a continuous function, there exist a (small) $\delta > 0$ such that $g(t) > 0$ for all $\lvert t - \tau \rvert < \delta$. Then take a function $f \in M$ defined by

$$
f(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $\lvert t - \tau \rvert \geq \delta$} \\
1 + (t - \tau)/\delta & \text{if $\tau - \delta \leq t \leq \tau$} \\
1 - (t - \tau)/\delta & \text{if $\tau \leq t \leq \tau + \delta $}.
\end{cases}$$
(Its graph is something like triangle wave which has peek at $t = \tau$ and its amplitude is $1$.)
Since $f \in M$ and $g \in M^\perp$, it should be $\langle f, g \rangle = 0$. However, from the choice of $\delta$ and $f$, it's also $\langle f, g \rangle > 0$. Contradiction.

%% Though I show in case $X$ is a set of continuous *real*-valued functions, the same argument would work in complex-valued case by separation of integral to real part and imaginary part.

Comment: Taro: Is true equality $ M \bigoplus M^{\perp}=X$? thanks

Comment: @nim If the inner product space is finite, the similar statement is well-known and it's true. I'm unsure about what happens in general (i.e., infinite inner product space). I recommend you ask that question independently. (I feel it's false in this case.)

Comment: If the inner product space is finite or Subspace of $ M $ be finite dimension, then, there is equality? which? thanks

Comment: @nim Let $W$ be a subspace of a finite inner product space $V$. Then $V = W \oplus W^\perp$ holds.

Comment: I found a proof. Assume constant function $1 \in X$ can be uniquely decomposed into $1 = f + g$ where $f \in M$ and $g \in M^\perp$. Then $1 = f(0) + g(0) = g(0)$ and $g(\varepsilon) = 0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. Thus, $g$ becomes discontinuous. Contradiction. Hence $M \oplus M^\perp \neq X$.

Comment: many thanks Taro.

Comment: Taro: I'm confused about this, Dose $ t \in (0,1) $ true or $ t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Why did $ t \in (0,1) $? why in the definition g did not consider $ t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: For the choice of $\delta$. If $\tau$ in the proof is $0$ or $1$, the argument above doesn't work. Though $N = \{\, g \in X \mid \text{$g(t) = 0$ for all $t \in (0, 1]$}\,\}$ since $g$ is continuous.

Comment: And from the same argument, $N = \{\, g \in X \mid \text{$g(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$}\,\}$. The representation is different but $N$ represents same set. I just use the first one for simplicity.

Comment: Really thank Taro. As a final question, So we have always in the question, $ M \bigoplus M^{\perp} =X $?

Comment: Always? In what context do you use $M$ and $X$? As I wrote in my first comment, if $X$ is finite dimensional inner product space then $X = M \oplus M^\perp$ holds. In this specific case, $X \neq M \oplus M^\perp$. And its proof is also in my comment above.

Comment: I have another question. What is $ M + N =?$ thanks Taro

Comment: $M \oplus M^\perp = \{\, f \in X \mid f(0) = 0 \,\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would conjecture that $M^\perp=\{g\in X:\forall t\in [0,1], g(t)=0\}$. Try to show equality of sets, and you may discover if this is indeed the case.